# Printing out an integer array ends with garbage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have following code which should print array of 3072 integers:

```
for(int q=0; q < 3072; q++) printf("%x", band->GetData(q));
```

one would assume that it will print 3072 integers, however I get 3075 integers with 3 probably garbage ones at the end. Printing to the file using this code

```
fp=fopen("filename", "w");
fwrite(band->GetBuffer(), sizeof(int), 3072, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

ends almost the same, except there are 3 extra bytes at the end. Use of different arrays gives different length of garbage.
I would like to ask why that happens and whether it is really a garbage.
Thank you.

```
int GetData(unsigned int pos) const { ASSERT(pos < m_size); return m_data[pos]; }
int* GetBuffer()    { return m_data; }
```

Comment: It returns size of the array, in this case 3072.

Comment: And what is the return type of `Band::GetData()`?  And if this is C++, why are you using `printf()` and `fwrite`?

Comment: How do you know band->GetData() works?

Comment: How can we guess what's wrong without seeing code for band->GetSize()?

Comment: That `fwrite` call makes no sense, the first argument is supposed to be a pointer to data, not an int.

Comment: GetData returns signed int, one member of array.

Comment: @Mat: Sorry, simplification in wrong place, fixed. band->GetBuffer() returns a pointer to array of signed ints.

Comment: How do you know how many integers you're printing with `printf` when there's no whitespace or other separators between them?

Comment: How does band get assigned?  It appears as if the internal size is incorrect from the start.  Has nothing to do with printing.  Also, the first param to fwrite is a buffer, not a integer.

Comment: Hello, @user982842. Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have shown us almost no code, and the problem you described can't follow from the code you have shown. Please reduce your program to a minimal, complete sample program that demonstrates the problem, and copy-paste (**not retype**) that program into your question. See http://sscce.org for information about how that helps you and us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the `fwrite` is probably because you've opened the file in text mode, and any `0x0a` bytes written to the file will be expanded to `0x0d 0x0a`.

The problem with the `printf` is that you're not putting out any separators between the numbers, so you're miscounting the output.

Comment: Thanks, the cause is really Windows CRLF and my misinterpretation of comparison between console and file output. Seems binary output is not so binary when writing to text file.

Comment: And way to fix it: `fopen("filename", "wb");`